# calculation $p$-Fitting subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ be a finite soluble group and $ A $ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $ G $ that $ \vert A \vert = p^{a} $, $ p $ is prime. Let $ N =Fit(G) $, then $ N = O_{p}(G) $. Suppose $ F/N = O_{p^{\prime}}(G/N) $. By the Schur–Zassenhaus theorem, there exists a subgroup $ V \leq F $ such that $ F = VN $ and $ V \cap N = 1 $. If $ L = N_{G}(V) $, then the Frattini argument yields $ G = LN $.  Now let $ A \leq L $, then $ [A , V] = 1 $. Let $ O_{p^{\prime}}(G/A) = T/A $. We can show  $ TN/N \leq F/N $ and hence $ T = A $. Now $ Fit_{p}(G) =\ ? $ Is it perhaps $ Fit_{p}(G) = O_{p^{\prime}p}(G/A) $ ?

Comment: I don't understand how you got $T=A$. Also, you should define $F_p(G)$.

Comment: Since $A$ is minimal normal, $[T,A] = 1$ or $A$. If $[T,A]=1$ then $A \le Z(T)$ and $T = A \times B$ with $B$ a $p'$-group and $B \unlhd G$. So, since $A$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup, $B=1$ and $T=A$. $ Fit_{p}(G) $ is the largest $ p $-nilpotent normal subgroup of $ G $.

Comment: You seem to have proved that either  $[T,A]=A$, or $T=A$. Since $O_{p'}(G)=1$, ${\rm Fit}_p(G) = {\rm Fit}(G) = N$.

Comment: If $G$ is any group with $O_{p'}(G)=1$, then ${\rm Fit}_p(G)={\rm Fit}(G)$.

Comment: Because you are assuming that $A$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$, and $A$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: Is it true that $ Fit_{p}(G) = O_{p^{\prime}p}(G/A) $ ?

Comment: Sorry, you are asking too many extra questions! I have answered your original question.